# Is it possible to group several http requests into one single check in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am updating one value and then need to check that api responds with the same value to me. The problem is, api returns array with only 100 objects and a timestamp that i need to add to the same request to see next 100 objects.Totally i need to check 450 obkects.

The first thing that come to my mind is just create 5 http requests (because I can only edit, not add new values, so it is cannot be more than 5 requests). But this isn't universal way of checking and i don't like it. Also i am confused because i know that after checking it will always be 4 false http request checks and only 1 successful (because needed item will be only in a single response).

1) Is it possible to group those requests into a single check, so JMeter gives me 1 success message in listener if he detects needed value in one of the 5 responses. And opposite if he doesn't.

2)May be you can propose more universal way, so if Jmeter detects needed value he will stop the test and also post success message, or opposite if he doesn't found value.

Comment: Maybe just Response Assertion (check that response contains 'someValue'). Add on the test plan level to apply to all requests.

Comment: Thanks, but this not solve the question that i am asked. As you see i receives unnecessary fails http://prntscr.com/b68k4i because needed value presents only in a single response. The question is i want to, somehow, union them into single check. So if JMeter can't find value in all responses he shows 1 fail message. If he finds value among all responses - he shows 1 success message.

Answer (score 0):

You can pack all responses into one string using Beanshell post-processor, and in the last one check if your string contains needed value. It's quite simple to continue afterwards... You can choose actions depending on what you get: if you get what you want, you can continue the test, print some output message, etc... And if needed value is not found you can stop the test through jmeter.engine.

This is the easiest way that I can think of, though it may not be the most efficient.

Comment: Actually i done pretty similar thing before your answer. I go through all responses and pack all objects into one array using bsf postprocessors. Than i only checks this array. 
Thanks